# php/mySql-Display image with path from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display images I have stored in the folder /img. 
My DB table stores info about the image path.

What I have so far:

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT image_path FROM news_image WHERE image_id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $filePath = $row['image_path'];
```

I want to display images something like this:

```
$image = echo '<img src="./' . $filePath . '" />';
```

How do I use the $id variable in the code above to get the correct image?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a problem with the query? Or would you like to display multiple images?

Comment: By all means, please ensure that you clean your `$_GET` input before using it in the query.  The code in your question is liable to sql injection.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from your use of `mysql_` queries (they are being depreciated) and that the posted code is open to SQL injection, everything looks like it should work. Only thing you need to do is get rid of the variable `$image` on this line:

```
$image = echo '<img src="./' . $filePath . '" />';
```

And simply use the following:

```
echo '<img src="./' . $filePath . '" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like this:

`$image = echo '<img src="./' . $filePath . '/'.$id.'.png" />';`

Basically the SRC will be `./FILEPATH/ID.png` assuming that's what you want.